# How to encode UTF8 filename for HTTP headers? (Python, Django)

Tags: python, django, http, http-headers, escaping

I have problem with HTTP headers, they're encoded in ASCII and I want to provided a view for downloading files that names can be non ASCII.

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % (vo.filename.encode("ASCII","replace"), )
```

I don't want to use static files serving for same issue with non ASCII file names but in this case there would be a problem with File system and it's file name encoding. (I don't know target os.)

I've already tried urllib.quote(), but it raises KeyError exception.

Possibly I'm doing something wrong but maybe it's impossible.

Comment: I realise I'm years late, but ... the KeyError exception really bugs me. I don't just mean "every once in awhile I run into this problem," I mean, I submitted a patch to Python to fix this years ago, argued for awhile, then decided they didn't want to change Python 2. I did fix this problem in Python 3, but they never accepted my patch in Python 2. The work-around is to .encode('utf-8') first, and then use urllib.quote. But that's for URL-encoding which isn't the standard way to put these in headers.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a FAQ.

There is no interoperable way to do this. Some browsers implement proprietary extensions (IE, Chrome), other implement RFC 2231 (Firefox, Opera).

See test cases at http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/.

Update: as of November 2012, all current desktop browsers support the encoding defined in RFC 6266 and RFC 5987 (Safari >= 6, IE >= 9, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Konqueror).

Comment: Thanks! Easiest things are the hardest to find ;)

Comment: More recently, Julian has put together a profile of RFC2231 for this purpose: http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-reschke-rfc2231-in-http/

Comment: Does this apply for multipart/form-data support, because right now I can see raw UTF-8 bytes sent in 'filename' parameter when uploading a file from a form in Chrome

Comment: jaime: No. See <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html#rfc.section.1.p.4>.

Comment: RFC 5987 as been obsoleted by [RFC 8187](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8187#section-3.2.3)

Comment: See my answer for a Django 2.1+  using FileResponse, now part of Django.

Answer (score 32):

Don't send a filename in Content-Disposition. There is no way to make non-ASCII header parameters work cross-browser(*).

Instead, send just “Content-Disposition: attachment”, and leave the filename as a URL-encoded UTF-8 string in the trailing (PATH_INFO) part of your URL, for the browser to pick up and use by default. UTF-8 URLs are handled much more reliably by browsers than anything to do with Content-Disposition.

(*: actually, there's not even a current standard that says how it *should* be done as the relationships between RFCs 2616, 2231 and 2047 are pretty dysfunctional, something that Julian is trying to get cleared up at a spec level. Consistent browser support is in the distant future.)

Comment: The top answer contains some great information, but you've actually solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Since this answer has come out, an RFC on this topic has been issued. Of note is the `filename*=` construct which only newer browsers support and is guaranteed to let you use UTF-8, encoded as in RFC 5987. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#appendix-D

Answer (score 32):

Note that in 2011, [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#appendix-D) (especially Appendix D) weighed in on this issue and has specific recommendations to follow.

Namely, you can issue a `filename` with only ASCII characters, followed by `filename*` with a RFC 5987-formatted filename for those agents that understand it.

Typically this will look like `filename="my-resume.pdf"; filename*=UTF-8''My%20R%C3%A9sum%C3%A9.pdf`, where the Unicode filename ("My Résumé.pdf") is encoded into UTF-8 and then percent-encoded (note, do NOT use `+` for spaces).

Please do actually read RFC 6266 and RFC 5987 (or use a robust and tested library that abstracts this for you), as my summary here is lacking in important detail.

Comment: This is what I needed for a file download endpoint in my Django project. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

Starting with **Django 2.1** (see issue [#16470](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16470)), you can use [`FileResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects), which will correctly set the `Content-Disposition` header for attachments. Starting with **Django 3.0** (issue [#30196](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30196)) it will also set it correctly for `inline` files.

For example, to return a file named `my_img.jpg` with MIME type `image/jpeg` as an HTTP response:

```
response = FileResponse(open("my_img.jpg", 'rb'), as_attachment=True, content_type="image/jpeg")
return response
```

Or, if you can't use `FileResponse`, you can use the relevant part from [`FileResponse`'s source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c70cd2a926ffab47f6613e83e0c8828eb6c2c064/django/http/response.py#L486-L492) to set the `Content-Disposition` header yourself. Here's what that source currently looks like:

```
from urllib.parse import quote

disposition = 'attachment' if as_attachment else 'inline'
try:
    filename.encode('ascii')
    file_expr = 'filename="{}"'.format(filename)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    file_expr = "filename*=utf-8''{}".format(quote(filename))
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = '{}; {}'.format(disposition, file_expr)
```

Comment: NOTE: if `as_attachment=False` (if `Content-Disposition` is `inline`) it is not available in either version **Django 2.1** or version **Django 2.2**, now (21.05.2019) it is in the **Django dev** version, so for the `inline` I use the manual version.

Comment: For more info about @don_vanchos's comment, see [Django issue #30196](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30196).

Answer (score 10):

I can say that I've had success using the newer ([RFC 5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987)) format of specifying a header encoded with the e-mail form ([RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231)). I came up with the following solution which is based on code from the django-sendfile project.

```
import unicodedata
from django.utils.http import urlquote

def rfc5987_content_disposition(file_name):
    ascii_name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', file_name).encode('ascii','ignore').decode()
    header = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(ascii_name)
    if ascii_name != file_name:
        quoted_name = urlquote(file_name)
        header += '; filename*=UTF-8\'\'{}'.format(quoted_name)

    return header

# e.g.
  # request['Content-Disposition'] = rfc5987_content_disposition(file_name)
```

I have only tested my code on **Python 3.4** with **Django 1.8**. So the similar [solution in django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile/blob/7a000e0e7ae1732bcea222c7872bfda6a97c495c/sendfile/__init__.py#L69) may suite you better.

There's a [long standing ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16470) in Django's tracker which acknowledges this but no patches have yet been proposed afaict. So unfortunately this is as close to using a robust tested library as I could find, please let me know if there's a better solution.

Comment: Awesome! The that need to!

Answer (score 3):

The `escape_uri_path` function from Django is the solution that worked for me.

Read the [Django Docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/_modules/django/utils/encoding/#escape_uri_path) to see which RFC standards are currently specified.

```
from django.utils.encoding import escape_uri_path

file = "response.zip"
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f"attachment; filename*=utf-8''{escape_uri_path(file)}"
```

Answer (score -1):

A hack:

```
if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("IE"))
{
  // IE will accept URL encoding, but spaces don't need to be, and since they're so common..
  filename = filename.Replace("%", "%25").Replace(";", "%3B").Replace("#", "%23").Replace("&", "%26");
}
```

Comment: User-agent sniffing stinks in general, [these buggy servers use it](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#buggy-senders) and are responsible for a lot of the tc2231/rfc6266 test cases.