# Django filename from database with non-ascii characters

Tags: python, django, utf-8

I'm trying to create a file dynamically in Django:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/txt')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename # UnicodeEncodeError

response.write('text')

return response
```

If I hardcode the filename it works properly, but if I try to create the filename from DB data that contains non-ascii characters (like ó) I get a UnicodeEncodeError exception. How can I use the DB filename without getting an exception?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode UTF8 filename for HTTP headers? (Python, Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361604/how-to-encode-utf8-filename-for-http-headers-python-django)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
...

 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(filename)
```

Comment: but not all utf symbols can be converted  ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the problem on the Django side but there is no guarantee it will work in all browsers.

See the testcases at http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/.

For more details on this see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361604/how-to-encode-utf8-filename-for-http-headers-python-django), which links to a snippet to handle most cases.

Comment: 10 years later, the "no guarantee it will work in all browsers" is longer true I think.