# How to stop HTTP (and rfc822, email) header injection?

Tags: python, http-headers, code-injection, email-headers, rfc822

(I am asking this question (and answering it), to make accessible some (hopefully useful) information, since I could not find this readily using search engines. However, feel free to answer it and add useful information :-).)

How can HTTP headers be escaped/quoted in Python?

And/Or how can they be validated to make sure they do not contain any context-escaping values?

In other words, how can we do for HTTP headers, what  `cgi.escape` and `urllib.quote` methods (and sanitizing) do for HTML and URLs? This can be used to guard against [HTTP header injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header_injection) and similar exploits.

## For example...

We have the user providing a URL to which one should be redirected. We want to protect against injection attacks (of which [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) is a well known one). Setting aside (for this discussion) security concerns (concerning surreptitious automatic forwarding to a URL in a domain which the user can choose), if we decide to redirect [using the `Location:` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_redirect#HTTP_status_codes_3xx), how can we escape the user-supplied URL to prevent HTTP-header injection (or detect if it contains values dangerous for HTTP)?

```
# on a "posix sh"-like command-line...
# ...(it contains a malicious HTTP value)
$ redirect_to 'http://example.com'"\r\n"'Set-Cookie: malicious=value'
```

Now, in our python code implementing the `redirect_to` command, we want to input like the above to either be escaped (rendering it harmless), or to be an error. How can we do so?

Answer (score 1):

If the input data is being included in a header field *parameter* (for example the [`filename` parameter of the `Content-Disposition` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266)), it can be encoded with [`email.utils.encode_rfc2231`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util#email.utils.encode_rfc2231) (as constrained by [these specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987#section-3), which define a variation of the [rfc2231 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987)).

If it is *not* being included a header field parameter, then it seems that this method cannot be used. In such a situation, the safest bet would likely be to just not include the input, as [Julian Reschke wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629098); however, if you insist on including the input, you may want to try one of the following methods:

(which may be insecure, since [HTTP is not a MIME-compliant protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.4), and so unless [the `MIME-Version` header is used](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.4.1) (and possibly even if it is used?), these ways **may not work correctly** for HTTP.)

## One way...

to do this, although it may not be totally foolproof (**edit**: it is *not* foolproof (when used by itself); it accepts `\r\n\r\n`, which terminates headers and starts the body! Therefore `\r` and `\n` would need to handled, unless preceded by non-`\r`/`\n` whitespace (like tabs or spaces.)), is to use the [`email.header`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header) module. This is designed specifically for [rfc822 headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-3.2) (**edit**: but (seemingly, since the email package used to be several separate modules ([example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetools))) [not for HTTP headers!](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2)), so would seem to be the tool for the job. This `Header` class is meant for encoding header *values*, not the full `Header-Name: value`, and so is a candidate for this job (where we want to vaidate or escape the value *only*).

(Hint: many of the tools in the `email` module are also handy when working with other MIME-format (**edit**: and possibly also MIME-like) stuff; so too stuff in the `cgi` module, `cgi.FieldStorage` in particular for HTTP-form parsing.)

However, [`email.header`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header) only will raise an error if the input seems *malicious* (seems to contain another (embedded) header); however, it will not, it seems, handle *invalid* input by escaping it (please correct this in the comments if it is not so). (The `charset` parameter should escape the header-fragment, returning *valid* input, however, it may not have such good compatibility with user agents (email, HTTP, etc.); see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1361604) (**edit**: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361646/541412>many HTTP user agents support (not necessarily the `charset` parameter of the encoding for the `email.header.Header` class (which seems to use some MIME-specific encodings besides rfc2231 encoding), but) the [rfc5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) encoding).

Example:

```
import email.header
import re

def check_string_for_rfc822_header(s):
    wip_header_component = str(email.header.Header(s))
    if re.search(r'(\r?\n[\S\n\r]|\r[\S\r])', wip_header_component):
        raise Exception
    else:
        return wip_header_component

# testing...
>>> check_string_for_rfc822_header("aaa")
"aaa"
>>> check_string_for_rfc822_header("a\r\nb")
"a\r\nb"
>>> check_string_for_rfc822_header("a\r\nb: c")
<error>
```

## Another way...

to do this, it seems, would be to simply [remove `\r` and `\n` characters](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17187) (each separately however; do not just remove occurences the full string `\r\n`, since this would still leave these unescaped when occuring separately, and many (most?) HTTP utils will accept each of them separately!). Similarly, we can escape the header by replacing `\r\n`, `\r`, and `\n`, with themselves prepended by whitespace (which is the way to escape header; see [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2)).

However, this method does not take into account the details of the standards (for example, rfc822 headers [must be ACSII](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2)), which may be exploitable on their own.

Example:

```
def remove_linebreakers(s):
    return s.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")

# or...
import re

def remove_linebreakers(s):
    re.sub(r'[\n\r]', '', s)


# testing...
>>> remove_linebreakers("aaa")
"aaa"
>>> remove_linebreakers("a\r\nb")
"ab"
>>> remove_linebreakers("a\r\nb: c")
"ab: c"
```

## In summary...

the first way seems better, but only for validation (not for escaping), unless it is a parameter value, in which case escape it using [`email.utils.encode_rfc2231`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util#email.utils.encode_rfc2231).

Example:

```
# if we are not working with a header param value, the following...
# ...raises email.errors.HeaderParseError if input is poisonous when in a header
wip_header_component = str(email.header.Header('<input>'))
header_component = (raise_error() if re.search(r'(\r?\n[\S\n\r]|\r[\S\r])', wip_header_component) else wip_header_component)
# ...or if we *are* working with a header param value...
email.utils.encode_rfc2231('<input>', 'UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape. Just stop processing (drop the header or the whole request).

Comment: I think that I did not explain myself properly in the question; I modified it (and its title), in an attempt to explain more.

Comment: I'd still just not generate the redirect. Just return 400.

Comment: Yup, I guess that makes more sense. I updated my answer, using [info I gleaned](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1361604) concerning working with filenames, which is my current use case, which I realized afterwards, [some of](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266) the standards concerning these topics, [were authored](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987) by you :-)