# Python smtplib and sanitization

Tags: python, security, bottle, sanitize, smtplib

I'm using a very basic (almost exactly [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)) utilization of smtplib. A subject and message are retrieved from a [Bottle FormsDict](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/api.html#bottle.FormsDict) using `request.forms.get()` and then emailed off using this code.

```
msg = MIMEText(message)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = config['from_email']
msg['To'] = config['to_email']
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(config['from_email'], [config['to_email']], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I'm used to sanitizing user input for XSS and such (usually just relying on Jinja2's magic). What should I be doing in this case though, where I'm only sending the user's input through email? What sort of vulnerabilities would there be?

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to figure out that myself right now and one thing I can tell you is that you should definitely use [email.header.Header](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html) to detect header injections:

```
from email.header import Header
>>> Header('Test').encode()
'Test'
>>> Header('Test\n').encode()
'Test'
>>> Header('Test\nTest2').encode()
'Test\nTest2'
>>> Header('Test\nFrom').encode()
'Test\nFrom'
>>> Header('Test\nFrom:').encode()
(...)
HeaderParseError: header value appears to contain an embedded header: 'Test\nFrom:'
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629098/176186) answer, I think I agree that if the input is potentially dangerous you should just reject it as that probably means someone is trying to do something sketchy.

EDIT:

It turns out that MIME messages validate headers on their own, even if you don't use  `email.header.Header`, and also nicely encode the body:

```
>>> msg = MIMEText('something\r\nsomething2', 'plain', 'UTF-8')
>>> msg.as_string()
'MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\nc29tZXRoaW5nDQpzb21ldGhpbmcy\n'
>>> msg['From'] = 'me@localhost\r\nSubject: injected subject'
>>> msg.as_string()
(...)
HeaderParseError: header value appears to contain an embedded header: 'me@localhost\nSubject: injected subject'
```

You can find more possible injections at [Is there any injection vulnerability in the body of an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341802/is-there-any-injection-vulnerability-in-the-body-of-an-email).

So I would say that you don't have to do anything special to stay on the safe side as:

- header injection is detected by default, so a hacker cannot add headers by messing with the  value of `subject`
- body is encoded/quoted so if there's any evil sequence of charatecter that could break something it should be neutralized
- even if body wasn't encoded, I think the only way to cause harm would be to change the message structure by e.g. injecting MIME boundary (for multipart messages; example: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=600464). But the boundary is a long random string so it would probably be easier to guess your bank password.
- `<CRLF>.<CRLF>` sequence [terminates message body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5342165/176186) but that is not a problem as MIME classes replace CRLF with LF:

  ```
  >>> MIMEText('something\r\n.\r\nsomething2', 'plain', _charset='iso-8859-1').as_string()
  'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\nsomething\n.\nsomething2'
  ```

Comment: The `<CRLF>.<CRLF>` thing is a red herring. Like it says in the answer you link to, it's only a problem if you are writing your own SMTP client. Above that level, it's handled transparently.

Comment: @tripleee Now I'm puzzled by how MIMEText sanitizes the input. According to http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-2.3 CR and LF should always go together, whereas MIMEText coverts CRLF to LF..

Comment: Apples and oranges. On the SMTP level all line terminators get changed to CRLF in transport. Dot stuffing is not the realm or responsibility of the MIME layer at all; it's a concern during the SMTP transaction only.

Comment: Good to know, one thing less to worry about.