# What is the encoding of http headers

Tags: http, web, encoding

The encoding of content is told by the header field "ContentType". But how do I know the encoding of this header field?
I mean the characters "ContentType" is encoded in UTF8 or sth else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode UTF8 filename for HTTP headers? (Python, Django)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361604/how-to-encode-utf8-filename-for-http-headers-python-django)

Answer (score 1):

Header field values are essentially US-ASCII, unless the definition of the header field says something else (right now, node does).

One way to encode non-ASCII characters is to use an overlay encoding such the one defined in RFC 5987 (but the header field definition still needs to opt into that).