# Encode filename according to rfc 5987 in python / tornado

Tags: python, tornado

From [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) I learnt that the encoding defined in RFC 5987 is used to encode filenames in `Content-disposition` headers. And from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361646/739619 I learnt that support in major browsers is good at least since November 2012. Both questions are rather old, yet I couldn't find a standard way to encode filenames according to this encoding in python / tornado. I have a

```
self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="{}.{}"'.format(basename, format))
```

in my code that fails when `basename` contains characters outside latin1, and I am loking for a standard way to encode it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) to encode. Just add the boilerplate of `filename*=UTF-8''`. For instance, this simple server serves a file with a UTF-8 filename:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

import urllib.parse

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        filename = 'file "\'ä↭.txt'
        encoded_filename = urllib.parse.quote(filename, encoding='utf-8')
        self.set_header(
            'Content-Disposition',
            'attachment;filename*=UTF-8\'\'{}'.format(encoded_filename))
        self.write('text file with file name file "\'ä↭.txt.\n')
        self.write('Most browsers will encode the " as _ or so.')


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Might want to note that it is [RFC2183](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2183) that restricts parameter values to US-ASCII.

Comment: ...well, it works in Firefox, while Chrome seems to ignore `filename*` and to accept `filename` with the encoded value. Also, it seems to me that the boilerplate `UTF-8''` is not needed, at least not in Chrome and in Firefox...

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome (v66.0.3359.45). If you remove the boilerplate, you're not using the new RFC 5987 behavior, but the old RFC 2616 one.

Comment: You are right, if I run a server with your code it works for me as well; if I run my complete code it doesn't. I am extending your example piece after piece to reach mine and see where it starts giving the problem, I didn't get there yet, but eventually I will :)

Comment: Got it, it was a typo so stupid that it's not worth mentioning :) now it works as it should. Thanks again!

Comment: This answer is insufficient. The characters encoded by `urllib.parse.quote` do not match the specs. For example, the urllib method will not escape `'` but the spec requires it. See `attr-char` from [RFC 5987 § 3.2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987#section-3.2.1) for the FULL list of characters that should not be percent-encoded. Everything else should be.

Comment: @AndrewF:  `quote()` encodes `'` too. Though  [`safe=""` is necessary to encode `/` too](https://replit.com/@zed1/rfc5987).

Comment: @jfs This was my confusion based on the linked document, which says: "Letters, digits, and the characters `'_.-~'` are never quoted." I don't know why someone would choose to put quotes inside a code block in the context of documenting a list of characters.